# Suppress Sections with Key in Preamble

Tags: conditionals

How do I suppress a section unless a line of code activates it or suppress it with a line of code that I can comment out? This line of code has to be placed at the top of the document.

For context, I am putting together a photography contract. 99\% of the time each section is one of a couple standard variations. Copyright, for example, is normally either all rights are sold to client or I hold copyright and the client may use the images in a non-commercial setting. I want to have all variants of each section in the one file document and the activate the appropriate ones based on which lines of code I comment out at the top of the page.

What I have been envisioning is a couple lines in the preamble that look something like this:

> %Copyright
>   line that hides section with all rights sold to client
>   %line that hides section with personal use only

Which, when rendered as PDF becomes:

> 1 Copyright
>   All rights are sold to client.

Comment: It's definitely easier if the sections would  be inside of separate files

Comment: @ChristianHupfer That's my current system, but it's not a flexible if changes come up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Will this do?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{environ}
\newif\ifcopyright
\copyrighttrue% defalult is \copyrightfalse

\NewEnviron{hidden}[1][]% #1 = warning message (optional)
{\ifcopyright #1\else\BODY\fi}

\begin{document}
This will always appear.

\begin{hidden}[\fbox{All rights sold to client.}]
This text is hidden.
\end{hidden}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Could I get you to explain what's happening? I'm pretty new to the TeX world.

Comment: \newif is used to create true/false flags.  \if...\else...\fi is the original (plain TeX) way to handle conditional compilation.  The environ package and \NewEnviron allow one to use \BODY to implement the contents of the environment.  (Keeping track of \if..\fi matches can be a pain.)

Comment: And it works like a charm. Thank you very much.